# control line break to create shapes

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, typography

I was wondering if I could do something like the image on the picture. I need to have control over the copy but don't know what the best technique would be. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Gon

[image: Line break to create diagonal]

Comment: It think you are looking for this http://www.csstextwrap.com/ ^^

Comment: http://www.csstextwrap.com/ would do the trick

Comment: Have a look at `CSS3 Regions` - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html If you're targeting modern browsers.

Comment: Guys, this is perfect!! Thanks very much to all of you!! How do I vote positive to your comments????? :(